# window.showModalDialog() opens up new ModalDialog instead of using existing Dialog

Tags: javascript

I have written `base target="_self"` tag in head tag.
It works fine in IE6 but not in IE8.
`window.showModalDialog()` opens up new `ModalDialog` instead of using existing `Dialog`.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: some clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try giving a name to the modal window.